Imaging Ubuntu to USB drive
I saw that to download the install file for Ubuntu is 6GB.   Does this mean that I can install Ubuntu on any USB drive with a capacity greater than 6GB?
Thanks

The actual answer is "YES".
A very simple tool to use for writing the file onto the USB-drive is: Balena Etcher
The USB-drive will boot up as a pure Linux, if you select "Try Ubuntu" as it comes up.
There are tools for all normal tasks, as in creating media, accessing an installed Linux OS partition and so on... so consider the USB-drive to be your rescue if you need to do something special.

This system (24.04 scratch install, on a 4TB NVME) was setup from a USB-drive created with Balena Etcher,
Device            Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048    2203647    2201600    1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  2203648    6397951    4194304    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3  6397952   14786559    8388608    4G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 14786560 7814033407 7799246848  3,6T Linux filesystem

... so not sure what the comment about legacy mode requirement (below) is about.

Also mention that it does not usually work unless you have legacy mode (CSM) enabled in the firmware and that you must select the option without UEFI in the boot menu. That is, unless your system is old and only runs legacy BIOS

UEFI for sure doesn’t work with Balena Etcher. Etcher sets the drive up for legacy BIOS.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview But I have see all these suggested: balenaEtcher, rufus, & Startup Disk Creator & mkusb
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb
